# Loop Add all even numbers

Tags: c#, loops, counter

How do I add all even numbers from 1000-2000 and display the total?
If you could help me I would be very thankful.

```
        int sum = 1000;
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter >= 2000)
        {
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum += counter; 
                counter++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Think about it a bit.  Why would you initialise the `sum` to 1000?  Would you do that if you were adding these numbers up on paper?  Also, if you initialise the `counter` to 1 then will `counter` ever be greater than or equal to 2000?

Comment: Your first three lines are wrong. The rest looks fine. Think about how the code will work: run it "in your head" for a few loops.

Comment: I may be too tired but ... `Console.Writeline(3000*501/2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sum = Enumerable
    .Range(1000, 1001)
    .Where(n => n % 2 == 0)
    .Sum();

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

To get your code to work you should have it look like this:

```
int sum = 0;
int counter = 1000;
while (counter <= 2000)
{
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        sum += counter; 
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Or you could do it this way:

```
int sum = 0;
for (var counter = 1000; counter <= 2000; counter ++)
{
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        sum += counter; 
    }
}
```

Or this way:

```
int sum = 0;
for (var counter = 1000; counter <= 2000; counter ++)
{
    sum += (counter % 2 == 0) ? counter : 0; 
}
```

This one is my favourite:

```
int sum = 0;
var counter = 1000;
loop:
    sum += (counter % 2 == 0) ? counter : 0; 
    if (++counter > 2000)
        goto exit;
    goto loop;
exit:
```

Hopefully you can now get an A+.

Comment: This is very likely a homework question, and we shouldn't be straight-up providing an answer: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems. Please remove your answer.

Comment: @musical_coder - Fair enough. I must admit it did look like there were a bunch of basic issues in the code.

Comment: Yep, there definitely are issues, but IMO the best way to help with homework is to just give hints.

Comment: @musical_coder - I should have caught on a little quicker. My mistake.

Comment: No problem. I'll lift my downvote, but hope you agree with me for the future about how to handle homework problems. Nice answers btw!